# Replacing only the text font in beamer with XeTeX

Tags: beamer, fonts, xetex, fontspec

I'm trying to make a beamer presentation in which only the text font is changed, but the math remains the same.  I would have thought that this would do it,

```
\documentclass[english]{beamer}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setsansfont{Arial}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
This is a test.  $f(x) = \pi \approx 3.14159$
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

but it replaces the math font as well, despite my use of the [no-math] option.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `unicode-math`  to set the math font:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}  % needed for fontspec to work properly in beamer

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont{Arial}

\usepackage{mathtools}  % should be loaded before unicode-math
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}  % or any of the other opentype math fonts

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
This is a test.  $f(x) = \pi \approx 3.14159$
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @MaxNoe, the problem is that that makes my math font all serif, and I can't find a unicode math font that looks just like Latin Modern Sans. Does that make sense?

Comment: You can also set it to a sans font, but you might encounter missing glyphs. Which could then be replaced by using another font for them.