# change whole font of beamer to arial bold italic?

Tags: beamer

how to change the font of the content to bold italic ?

thank you

here my cool superbe example:

```
\documentclass[14pt,t]{beamer}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{grffile}
\begin{frame}\maketitle\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{test0}
\begin{itemize}
\item test
\item test
\begin{itemize}
\item test
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

A possible solution would be to use:

```
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{phv}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv}
%\renewcommand{\mddefault}{b}   % this content bold with b
\renewcommand{\bfdefault}{phv} % Helvetica has no bx series
\renewcommand{\updefault}{sl}
```

But it does do helvel arial bold for the whole document, and maybe there are ways to have the items/text of the slides in bold italic, and to keep normal phv for the top of the slide (frame title)?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your question title suggests you want to use Arial, your question's body does not. What do you want?

Comment: i want helvet, ie this free arial like font of default linux

Comment: Well, I do not know default linux (a kernel has a font???), but why don't you load the package `helvet` and redefine `\mdseries` to mean `\bfseries`?

Comment: have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59779/setting-font-attributes-in-beamer

Comment: or with xelatex: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/300694/replacing-only-the-text-font-in-beamer-with-xetex

Comment: Your "cool superbe example" does not compile. Furthermore you should not load `\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}` with beamer - it already provides it.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[14pt,t]{beamer}

\setbeamerfont*{normal text}{family={\fontfamily{phv}}, series=\bfseries, shape=\itshape}
\AtBeginDocument{\usebeamerfont*{normal text}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{test0}
\begin{itemize}
\item test
\item test
\begin{itemize}
\item test
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]